# Selecting an option will select an other option

Tags: javascript, html-select

For example, if you select the option with `id="chocolate-yes"` or `id="vanilla-yes"`, the the option with `id="icecreamcone-yes"` will also be selected.

Anyone know of a Javascript that can do this?

***Note 1: the option with `id="sprinkles-yes"` will not effect `id="icecreamcone-yes"`.

Note 2: id names cannot be changed, nor can you add more properties to the elements.

Note 3: cannot use jQuery.***

```
<ul id="icecream" style="list-style:none;line-height:30px;">
  <li>
    <select id="icecreamcone">
      <option value="addicecreamcone">Would you like an ice cream cone?</option>
      <option id="icecreamcone-yes" value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option id="icecreamcone-no" value="no">No thanks</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select id="vanilla">
      <option value="addvanilla">Would you like to add vanilla ice cream?</option>
      <option id="vanilla-yes" value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option id="vanilla-no" value="no">No thanks</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select id="chocolate">
      <option value="addchocolate">Would you like to add chocolate ice cream?</option>
      <option id="chocolate-yes" value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option id="chocolate-no" value="no">No thanks</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select id="sprinkles">
      <option value="addsprinkles">Would you like to add sprinkles on top?</option>
      <option id="sprinkles-yes" value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option id="sprinkles-no" value="no">No thanks</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: is this homework ? (*i am asking due to the many restrictions*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
document.getElementById("chocolate").onchange = function(){
  if(document.getElementById("chocolate").options[1].selected == true) {
    document.getElementById("icecreamcone").options[1].selected = true
  }
}
```

When you select th select Chocolate IceCream to Yes, it will automatically set Icecrem Cone to Yes as well.

Comment: Thanks nxtwrld, but your example only works when you select chocolate, it doesn't work for vanilla.

Comment: Just copy it and replace chocolate with vanilla.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks. However, if for example, I would have 50 flavors, can you show me how to get the same result with less code?